# Disappearing question that resurfaces

Tags: discussion

I am intrigued by what appears to be a question that disappeared and then resurfaced an hour later, seemingly identical to the original.
The question is now *[List Assignment Out of Range - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162501/list-assignment-out-of-range-python)*.

I provided an answer to that very question an hour and a half ago, apparently an hour before it was asked. I also note, if memory serves, the comments are different, so it appears to have been removed along with all of the original input.

I'm, just wondering if it serves any purpose to allow questions to be deleted only to be posted back unchanged?

Hoping for a different response, one assumes.

Comment: If you had posted an answer, you should be able to find it in your action history. Or at least in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4637585+deleted%3A1

Comment: @Bergi That link only works at 10k.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

They deleted the previous version, and reposted a new version with a slightly different title and an extra sentence at the beginning. The system only blocks *exact* duplicate texts. They may have even gotten blocked trying to repost it and made the tiny changes to bypass it.

Comment: Thanks for coming back, at first I thought that I was losing my marbles.

Comment: Maybe a moderator like yourself could undelete the previous question and merge them if the answer @Rolf is worthwhile.

Answer (score 23):

Deleting and re-posting questions is not appropriate.

If you realize someone is deleting and then re-posting the same question, flag the post for moderator attention describing the issue.  If you still have a link to the deleted question, it would be helpful to provide it.

Comment: @canon It's not difficult at all.  It wasn't too easy before the Reopen queue, but that's been around for many years now.  Getting a question that has really been fixed reopened is easy, and that will give it more attention, and by far the fastest way to get upvotes is to have a highly downvoted great question.  The problem is that people don't bother to actually fix their questions, they just re-post them until someone slips in a low quality answer before the question gets closed.

Comment: @canon If the question isn't even closed, just downvoted, then nothing is inhibiting it from getting an answer.

Comment: @canon On the homepage, yes, on the question list, google, or search, no.